# Using rank-nullity theorem to prove surjectivity and a question on injectivity

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

[image]

For injectivity, the proof starts with suppose $[v]_B = 0$, I'm not sure how this shows. I would think that simply saying, suppose $[v]_B = [w]_B$ and showing $v = w$ is the way to go and that comes out right away, could someone explain what the lecturer is doing here?

For surjectivity i don't see how he used the rank nulity theorem. I mean, is the dimension of the image the same as the dimension of $k^n$? Is the image $k^n$?

Also, why is the dimension of the kernal 0? that would mean that there are no vectors such that $[v]_B = 0$ no?

Comment: For injectivity the lecturer uses the fact, that it is sufficient so prove, that $\ker [.]_B= \{0\}$, if you already know, that the map is linear. By definition the nullity of the map is the dimension of its kernel, so the rank has to be $n$ by the rank nullity theorem.

Comment: @JBantje could you explain why that is? Why is the dimension of the kernal 0? Does that mean that there are no vectors $v$ so that $[v]_B = 0$?

Comment: There is precisely one, namely $v=0$ itself. Anyway, let's do a quick proof. Suppose $A$ is linear, its kernel is $\{ 0 \}$, and $Ax=Ay$. Then by linearity $Ay=A(x+y-x)=Ax+A(y-x)$. Hence $A(y-x)=0$; but since the kernel is $\{ 0 \}$ we have $y-x=0$ hence $y=x$. So $A$ is injective.

Comment: If $v$ is in the kernel, then by definition $[v]_B=0$ and therefore $v= 0 b_1 + \ldots + 0 b_n=0$ as already stated above in your screenshot. We now know that every element of the kernel is already $0$. The dimension of $\{0\}$ is zero.

Comment: @ian why is it's kernal $\{0\}$ if A is linear?

Comment: I didn't say that: I assumed $A$ is linear *and* has kernel $\{ 0 \}$, and concluded that $A$ is injective. In your problem you had to prove separately that the kernel is $\{ 0 \}$.

Answer (score 2):

$ \DeclareMathOperator\dim{dim} $If a subspace $E$ is contained in another subspace $F$ and if $\dim E=\dim  F$, then $E=F$.

From the rank-nullity theorem also results that for a linear map $\,\,f\colon E\rightarrow F$ with $ \dim E=\dim F $, $ f $ injective $\iff f$ surjective $ \iff f$ bijective.